# PostgreSQL: Numeric field overflow on decimal / numeric Data Type - Why does it gives this Error

Tags: sql, postgresql, sqldatatypes

I create a table like this

```
CREATE TABLE foo (
    id serial CONSTRAINT id_pk PRIMARY KEY,
    bar varchar(256),
    test decimal(5,5)
);
```

I then want to populate the `test` column

```
 INSERT INTO foo (test) VALUES (12345.12345)
```

This gives me

> Numeric field overflow
> Detail: A field with precision 5, scale 5must round to an absolute value less than 1.

I do not understand this. I though if I set a column to `decimal(5,5)`, I *must* have five digits to the left of the comma and five digits to the right of the comma. I have that with the number `12345.12345`.

Why does it give me this error?

Comment: Because decimal precision is not what you think it is. The first number is the *total number* of decimal digits, not the number of digits before the separator. You want `decimal(10, 5)`.

Comment: Try with `DECIMAL(10,5)`. Parameter on left side of comma is total length, parameter on right side I number of decimals.

Comment: The `psql` tag refers to the command line tool and is irrelevant here. Please do not add it

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You misunderstood how specifying a decimal works (and it is a bit confusing I agree).

[Quote from the manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-numeric.html#DATATYPE-NUMERIC-DECIMAL)

> The precision of a numeric is the total count of significant digits in the whole number, that is, the number of digits to both sides of the decimal point. The scale of a numeric is the count of decimal digits in the fractional part, to the right of the decimal point

So the first number defines the **total** number of digits, the second one defines the number of decimals.

If you want 5 digits before the decimal point and five after it, you need to use `decimal(10,5)`

Comment: @Stophface . . . Just to emphasize:  This is how SQL defines scale and precision, so it works like this in all databases, not just Postgres.